# when i open views of asp.net core mvc, visual studio crashes

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX8VR.png)

when i open views of asp.net core mvc only, visual studio crashes. I have updated visual studio 20022 but nothing has changed. visual studio 2022 is working asp.net core web api and other only has the problem in the picture.

Comment: Have you tried to restart your visual studio? You can  [report a problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022) and provide a recording if possible.